# svn - make local branch same as remote branch

Tags: svn, version-control

So I have already check out a remote svn branch (version 12345) to my local, and I made some changed on the local one, I have not committed yet.
Then I realized that the requirement changed so I actually do not need the local changes. How can I change the local files back (to version 12345)?

I know this can be done by deleting the local files and check out the whole remote svn branch again, but the files are big so I don't want to delete and check out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [revert](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.revert) your files. More details [svn help revert](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html).